# PHP Connection to LDAP fails randomly until Apache restart

Tags: php, apache, ldap, openldap

I have a PHP application which authenticates Active Directory users via ldap, however periodically, the ldap connection apparently fails until Apache is restarted. Once it is in this "failed state", nobody can log in until the restart.

This sometimes happens 3 or 4 times in one day or sometimes it goes for days or weeks without a problem. I cannot pinpoint any specific scenario which triggers the problem.

I have tried connecting using the hostname and the IP address but this occurs with both.

The error number return is 110, which is a connection timeout.

Apache/2.4.6 (Unix)

PHP/5.4.21

OpenLDAP Version 20437

ldap.max_links  Unlimited

```
<?php
$username= "myuser";
$host    = "192.168.0.38";
$user_dn = "DOMAIN\\$username";
$base_dn = "OU=Organization,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=ch";
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7); //to get debug info
if ($ldap_handle = ldap_connect($host)) {
    $bind_result = ldap_bind($ldap_handle, $user_dn, $password);
    if ($bind_result) { 
        $filter    = "(samaccountname=$username)";
        $justthese = array("givenname","sn","displayname","mail","st","samaccountname","telephonenumber");
            $sr        = ldap_search($ldap_handle, $base_dn, $filter,$justthese);
            $info      = ldap_get_entries($ldap_handle, $sr);
            ldap_close(); //edit as per comment below
            return $info;
        } else {
            $error=ldap_error($ldap_handle);
            ldap_close(); //edit as per comment below
            return array("error"=>$error);
        }
    } else {
        $error=ldap_error($ldap_handle);
        ldap_close(); //edit as per comment below
        return array("error"=>$error);
    }
?>
```

The Apache  log contains:

> ** ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 Outstanding Requests:
>    * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
>      outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
>     ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
>   ** ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 Response Queue:
>    * msgid 2,  type 100
>     ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 response count 1
>   ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 msgid 2 all 1
>   ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 NULL
>   ldap_int_select
>   read1msg: ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 msgid 2 all 1
>   read1msg: ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 msgid 2 message type search-result
>   read1msg: ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 0 new referrals
>   read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 msgid 2
>   request done: ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 msgid 2
>   res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
>   ldap_free_request (origid 2, msgid 2)
>   adding response ld 0x7f82f81d92e0 msgid 2 type 101:
>   ldap_parse_result
>   ldap_first_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_values_len
>   ldap_next_attribute
>   ldap_get_dn
>   ldap_free_connection 1 1
>   ldap_send_unbind
>   ldap_free_connection: actually freed
>   ldap_msgfree
>   ldap_create
>   ldap_bind_s
>   ldap_simple_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind
>   ldap_send_initial_request
>   ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
>   ldap_int_open_connection
>   ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_new_socket: 52
>   ldap_prepare_socket: 52
>   ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 52 tm: -1 async: 0
>   attempting to connect: 
>   ldap_create
>   ldap_bind_s
>   ldap_simple_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind
>   ldap_send_initial_request
>   ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
>   ldap_int_open_connection
>   ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_new_socket: 56
>   ldap_prepare_socket: 56
>   ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 56 tm: -1 async: 0
>   attempting to connect: 
>   ldap_create
>   ldap_bind_s
>   ldap_simple_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind
>   ldap_send_initial_request
>   ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
>   ldap_int_open_connection
>   ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_new_socket: 54
>   ldap_prepare_socket: 54
>   ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 54 tm: -1 async: 0
>   attempting to connect: 
>   connect errno: 110
>   ldap_close_socket: 52
>   ldap_err2string
>   ldap_err2string
>   ldap_create
>   ldap_bind_s
>   ldap_simple_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind
>   ldap_send_initial_request
>   ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
>   ldap_int_open_connection
>   ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_new_socket: 58
>   ldap_prepare_socket: 58
>   ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 58 tm: -1 async: 0
>   attempting to connect: 
>   connect errno: 110
>   ldap_close_socket: 56
>   ldap_err2string
>   ldap_err2string
>   ldap_create
>   ldap_bind_s
>   ldap_simple_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind
>   ldap_send_initial_request
>   ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
>   ldap_int_open_connection
>   ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_new_socket: 33
>   ldap_prepare_socket: 33
>   ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 33 tm: -1 async: 0
>   attempting to connect: 
>   connect errno: 110
>   ldap_close_socket: 54
>   ldap_err2string
>   ldap_err2string
>   ldap_create
>   ldap_bind_s
>   ldap_simple_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind_s
>   ldap_sasl_bind
>   ldap_send_initial_request
>   ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
>   ldap_int_open_connection
>   ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_new_socket: 52
>   ldap_prepare_socket: 52
>   ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.0.38:389
>   ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 52 tm: -1 async: 0
>   attempting to connect: 
>   connect errno: 110
>   ldap_close_socket: 58
>   ldap_err2string
>   ldap_err2string
>   connect success
>   ldap_open_defconn: successful
>   ldap_send_server_request
>   ldap_result ld 0x7f82f8164f00 msgid 1
>   wait4msg ld 0x7f82f8164f00 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
>   wait4msg continue ld 0x7f82f8164f00 msgid 1 all 1
>   ** ld 0x7f82f8164f00 Connections:
>   * host: 192.168.0.38  port: 389  (default)
>     refcnt: 2  status: Connected
>     last used: Wed May 14 15:50:27 2014
>
> ** ld 0x7f82f8164f00 Outstanding Requests:
>    * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
>      outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
>     ld 0x7f82f8164f00 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
>   ** ld 0x7f82f8164f00 Response Queue:
>      Empty
>     ld 0x7f82f8164f00 response count 0
>   ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7f82f8164f00 msgid 1 all 1
>   ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7f82f8164f00 NULL
>   ldap_int_select
>   read1msg: ld 0x7f82f8164f00 msgid 1 all 1
>   read1msg: ld 0x7f82f8164f00 msgid 1 message type bind
>   read1msg: ld 0x7f82f8164f00 0 new referrals
>   read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x7f82f8164f00 msgid 1
>   request done: ld 0x7f82f8164f00 msgid 1
>   res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
>   ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
>   ldap_parse_result
>   ldap_msgfree
>   ldap_search
>   put_filter: "(samaccountname=stfra)"
>   put_filter: simple
>   put_simple_filter: "samaccountname=stfra"
>   ldap_build_search_req ATTRS: givenname sn displayname mail st samaccountname telephonenumber l c st postalcode physicaldeliveryofficename streetaddress title facsimiletelephonenumber
>   ldap_send_initial_request
>   ldap_send_server_request
>   ldap_result ld 0x7f82f8164f00 msgid 2
>   wait4msg ld 0x7f82f8164f00 msgid 2 (infinite timeout)
>   wait4msg continue ld 0x7f82f8164f00 msgid 2 all 1
>   ** ld 0x7f82f8164f00 Connections:
>   * host: 192.168.0.38  port: 389  (default)
>     refcnt: 2  status: Connected
>     last used: Wed May 14 15:50:27 2014

Comment: Are you closing your connections on all your scripts?

Comment: I agree with @kwolfe, try calling `ldap_close();` so you aren't leaving orphaned open connections.

Comment: @ThomasEllis I tried this (updated code above) but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are not closing connections.
Wrap ldap_connect to the class with  lazy initialization 
and put connection close command to the destructor

Comment: I will try that and see if it helps. It certainly seems likely.

Comment: I added in ldap_close() prior to all "return" statements in the above however I am still experiencing the issue.